Unable to easily create prereleases using Nx
I'm struggling figuring out how to succinctly get prereleases to work properly using Nx.  If I run the command:
npx nx release version --projects myPackage --specifier prerelease --preid alpha
It will create a version of my package like myPackage v1.0.1-alpha.0 as I want and then update other packages that depend on myPackage to use the prerelease version, great!  However, if I then try to run the command to publish my packages for real:
npx nx release
I get the following error:
The "release" top level command cannot be used with granular git configuration. Instead, configure git options in the "release.git" property in nx.json, or use the version, changelog, and publish subcommands or programmatic API directly.

Okay--so I move the git config in nx.json from the version section to the release section.  But if I do that that, the first command above will now fail for a similar reason.  The next thing I tried to do was put the git config back into the version section then run:
npx nx release --projects myProject --specifier prerelease;
But the problem with this is I can't pass in --preid as an arg so it generates prerelease versions as 1.0.0-0.  It also generates CHANGELOG with prereleases in it which I don't want.
I'm very perplexed on how I can have a single nx.json config file and publish prereleases along with normal releases.  I can get something working, but it involves me moving the git section around in nx.json which isn't feasible in a CI/CD pipeline.
I believe I can get it working if I do version, changelog, and publish commands as separate steps, but this adds overhead and then I have to make the git commit myself, etc.  I feel like there should be a simpler way and maybe I'm not seeing it.
nx.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "defaultBase": "staging",
  "release": {
    "projectsRelationship": "independent",
    "version": {
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "generatorOptions": {
        "fallbackCurrentVersionResolver": "disk",
        "updateDependents": "auto"
      },
      "git": {
        "commit": false,
        "stageChanges": false,
        "tag": true
      }
    },
    "changelog": {
      "projectChangelogs": true,
      "automaticFromRef": true
    },
    "projects": ["packages/*"]
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/eslint/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "lint"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/storybook/plugin",
      "options": {
        "buildStorybookTargetName": "build-storybook",
        "serveStorybookTargetName": "storybook",
        "testStorybookTargetName": "test-storybook",
        "staticStorybookTargetName": "static-storybook"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/webpack/plugin",
      "options": {
        "buildTargetName": "build",
        "serveTargetName": "serve",
        "previewTargetName": "preview"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/jest/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "test"
      }
    }
  ],
  "targetDefaults": {
    "@nx/js:tsc": {
      "cache": true,
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "inputs": ["default", "^default"]
    },
    "stylelint": {
      "inputs": ["default", "{workspaceRoot}/.stylelintrc(.(json|yml|yaml|js))?"],
      "cache": true
    }
  }
}

project.json:
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "{projectRoot}/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/js:tsc",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "{projectRoot}/dist",
        "main": "{projectRoot}/src/index.ts",
        "tsConfig": "{projectRoot}/tsconfig.build.json",
        "rootDir": "{projectRoot}/src"
      }
    },
    "install": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": ["npm clean-install --prefix {projectRoot}"]
      }
    }
  }
}


I had the same problem and I was able to fix it by removing the git configuration that was inside release.changelog and just putting it in the release object. I understand that this may be happening in your case since you have it inside release.version:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "defaultBase": "staging",
  "release": {
    "projectsRelationship": "independent",
    "version": {
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "generatorOptions": {
        "fallbackCurrentVersionResolver": "disk",
        "updateDependents": "auto"
      }
      // "git": {
      //   "commit": false,
      //   "stageChanges": false,
      //   "tag": true
      // }
    },
    "changelog": {
      "projectChangelogs": true,
      "automaticFromRef": true
    },
    "projects": ["packages/*"]
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/eslint/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "lint"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/storybook/plugin",
      "options": {
        "buildStorybookTargetName": "build-storybook",
        "serveStorybookTargetName": "storybook",
        "testStorybookTargetName": "test-storybook",
        "staticStorybookTargetName": "static-storybook"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/webpack/plugin",
      "options": {
        "buildTargetName": "build",
        "serveTargetName": "serve",
        "previewTargetName": "preview"
      }
    },
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/jest/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "test"
      }
    }
  ],
  "targetDefaults": {
    "@nx/js:tsc": {
      "cache": true,
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "inputs": ["default", "^default"]
    },
    "stylelint": {
      "inputs": ["default", "{workspaceRoot}/.stylelintrc(.(json|yml|yaml|js))?"],
      "cache": true
    }
  }
}


Only as a comment:
What happened to me, so that you can have it as an example, was the following:
{
// ... config ...
  "release": {
    "projects": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "projectsRelationship": "independent",
    "git": {
      "commit": true,
      "tag": true
    },
    "version": {
      "generatorOptions": {
        "currentVersionResolver": "git-tag",
        "specifierSource": "conventional-commits"
      }
    },
    "changelog": {
      // "git": {
      //   "commit": false,
      //   "stageChanges": false,
      //   "tag": true
      // }
      "projectChangelogs": {
        "renderOptions": {
          "authors": true,
          "commitReferences": true,
          "versionTitleDate": true
        }
      },
      "workspaceChangelog": {
        "renderOptions": {
          "authors": true,
          "commitReferences": true,
          "versionTitleDate": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

